# Small bash script to quickly edit scripts in $PATH

Tags: bash, shell

Staying true to the mantra: *"The third time you do something, you automate"*, I've built up a decent collection of shell scripts that live in `~/bin`. Some of these scripts contain useful boilerplate code, or just stuff I can't bring myself to memorise (like colour output stuff). Other scripts I find myself elaborating on from time to time. Though not a great pain, I am very lazy. Rather than typing `vim ~/bin/some_script`, I've written yet another script that expands `some_script` to its full path (using `which`), and opens it in vim. I'm perfectly happy with how the script works, and added a few basic creature-comforts, like checking if any (valid) arguments were provided and so on. Truth be told, I've not been writing that much bash in recent years, and some of the expressions/tricks I found myself using feel clunky. I know I used to have something like this in my `.profile`, but that particular incarnation of the script/function never made it to my github misc repo.

In short, I'd like to know if there's some stuff I could improve on. First the code, then some specific things that just don't feel right to me.

```
Usage() {
    cat <<-__EOF_
${0##*/} finds executables in PATH and opens them in vim - useful to quickly edit your scripts
    -o         : opens all scripts using o flag (equivalent to vim -o <paths>)
    -O         : similar to -o, but uses -O flag (so vim -O <paths>)
    -h         : Display help message

__EOF_
    exit "${1:-0}"
}

flags=""
paths=""

while getopts :oOh f; do
    case $f in
        o)
            flags="-o"
            ;;
        O)
            flags="-O"
            ;;
        h)
            Usage
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown flag ${f}${OPTARG}"
            Usage 1
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

[ $# -lt 1 ] && echo "No arguments given" && Usage 2

for b in "$@"; do
    p=$(which "${b}") && paths="${paths} ${p}"
done
[ ${#paths} -gt 0 ] || :(){ echo "No valid executables found in path" && exit 3; };:

# We want globbing and word splitting here
# shellcheck disable=SC2086
vim $flags $paths
```

Things that just feel a tad off would be:

- `[ $# -lt 1 ] && echo "No arguments given" && Usage 2` I do this all the time, and it works just fine, but chaining together 3 commands with `&&` like this just looks ugly. If there's a cleaner, more concise way to do the same thing, I'm all ears.
- `p=$(which "${b}") && paths="${paths} ${p}"`. I'm not sold on the use of the subshell here. I'm using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` for my hashbang, I'm not sure I need the subshell. If not, what would be the alternative? What are the pro's, what are the con's?
- `[ ${#paths} -gt 0 ] || :(){ echo "No valid executables found in path" && exit 3; };:` same as chaining things, only this time, because I'm using an `||`, then an `&&`, I just wrap the last 2 expressions in a function and call it. This smells IMO. I could change it to `[ ${#paths} -le 0 ] && ...`, but then it's just another chain. Personally, I prefer `-gt` over `-le` or `-eq` in this case. I also prefer to have the eventual command (`vim`) to be the last one, so that the exit code of vim is passed back on success (without needing an explicit exit like `[ ${#paths} -gt 0 ] && vim $flags $paths && exit` or `exit $?` if want to be super-explicit)

There might be other things I can improve on, so feel free to point them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Use a shebang</strike>

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

I see you're already doing that.

In bash, prefer `[[...]]` over `[...]`. The double bracket [conditional
command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b)
gives you more features (including regular expression matching), and fewer
surprises (particularly about unquoted variables).

With a `getopts` loop, I prefer to `shift` at the end:

```bsh
while getopts ...; do
    case $opt in
        ...
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

Allow the Usage function to take an error message:

```bsh
Usage() {
    [[ -n $2 ]] && echo "$2" >&2
    # ... rest is the same
}
```

That simplifies some assertions

```bsh
(( $# > 0 )) || Usage 2 "No arguments given"
```

[Use `command -v` instead of `which`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/7552)

Use an array to hold the paths. There's no other good way to hold a list of things where any of them might contain whitespace.

```bsh
paths=()
for b in "$@"; do
    p=$( command -v "$b" ) && paths+=("$p")
done
```

You do need to command substitution (aka subshell) so you can capture the output.

The "colon" function makes me cringe.
For clarity, use `if` instead of long boolean chains

```bsh
if (( ${#paths[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "No valid executables found in PATH" >&2
    exit 3
fi
```

And [prefer quoting over word splitting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells):

```bsh
vim $flags "${paths[@]}"
```

Yes, the script will exit with vim's exit status. If you want to be super tidy, you could *replace* the script process with vim:

```bsh
exec vim $flags "${paths[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The colon function felt dirty to write indeed. Just out of curiosity: any specific reason to use `(())` for numeric comparisons over `[ -eq ]` & co? I get why one would prefer using `>` of `-gt`, but oddly enough, I find myself making less silly mistakes using the latter (I probably mess up `<` vs `>` at least once a week - embarrassing, I know)

Comment: Just a personal preference. `((...))` allow you to assign variables within it , and also to refer to variables without `$` to create readable C-like expressions -- `((sum += hours * hourly_rate))`

Comment: `((...))` does not play well with `set -e` though: if the arithmetic expression evaluates to zero, the return status is 1 -- makes it good for conditions, but can be confusing source of errors.

Comment: cheers. In that case, I'll stick to the square brackets for bash scripts. Implemented pretty much all of the other suggestions you made.